# <base href="" > tag does not work on mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use url rewrite with my .htaccess file.

First change when I had, I had a css base problem. Because I am using like folder place with my php files. (e.g: localhost/myproject/page/login)

So I solve my problem with using dynamically `<base href="" >`

Btw my theme is responsive, so I saw css problems when I try to check my theme with my mobile phone. Same pages cant use the `<base href="" >` tag.

But on my localhost (in my computer) everything is okay. I don't understand why can be happened? Are there any dependency with mobile browsers?

Do you have any idea? Or something else which I should know?

Comment: Try to avoid using `<base />` as it complicates navigation and investigating issues. Why can't you fix your links in-place without using `base`?

Comment: because i have parts of html code. do you any offer for me?

Comment: I suggest changing your links and references to use root-relative paths instead of base-relative paths.

Comment: @Dai what about link used in CSS files, e.g background-images. sometimes is not possible to change all the links. also `base` supposed to work in all browsers.

Comment: @Mehmet did you find the solution?